# iOS Application: Portable Data Storage of many Key/Values

Tags: ios, json, xcode, core-data, mobile

What is a good way to store many key/value pair entries in a mobile (iOS) application, such that they can be easily exported/imported?

I have considered a single large JSON file - would this be too slow/large with 200,000+ entries?

I have also considered CoreData - but could the data be moved easily via, for example, email?

Think of an address book. Contacts can be easily imported/exported, what data storage model would be comparable?

Thank you.

EDIT: Examples

1. Notes - be able to select and view short notes in a table. Each note is < 100 characters.
2. Saved bookmarks - each bookmark is stored in a table.

Comment: It really depends on how you expect to use this data in an app.

Comment: Example Uses: 1. Notes - be able to select and view short notes in a table. Each note is < 100 characters. 2. Saved bookmarks - each bookmark is stored in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have considered a single large JSON file - would this be too
>   slow/large with 200,000+ entries?

I don't know.  I can make a guess.  The guess would be yes, it's both too large and too slow.  However, you can always test it to find out.

> I have also considered CoreData - but could the data be moved easily
>   via, for example, email?

That depends on how you want to share the data.  You call email easy?

Core Data is a framework.  You can use any type of backend you want (you can even write your own).  The most common is probably SQLite.

If you use Core Data, you can keep the data files in a separate subdirectory and copy them just like any other file.

However, if you want to share data via an online service, you may want the ability to import/export JSON files.

If you are talking about synchronization, then that's a different beast entirely.

Basically, there is no single right answer.  You have to assess your requirements, and then determine which solution meets your needs.

On the surface, it seems like using Core Data would be a good fit, but it depends on how you want to use the data in your application.  Only you know that answer.